# How to force style injection when using cordova, webpack and style-loader

Tags: cordova, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have set up cordova with the webpack plugin, sass-loader for compiling sass, and style-loader for injecting the styles. I run cordova using the command `cordova run -- --livereload;` so that I see the results in both simulator and chrome browser.

The results are as expected, and everything is working fine. However, when I change the code inn app.scss, I get "compiled successfully", but I have to rerun cordova to see the changes. What am I not getting here? I should be able to see the changes right away, right?

My app.js

```
// Scripts Dependencies
import 'bootstrap';

// Styles Dependencies
import "../www/assets/app.scss";
```

My app.scss

```
@import "scss/header";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$primary: green;
$secondary: #fff;

body {
  background-color: $primary;
  color: $secondary;
}
```

And my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/assets/js/'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(scss)$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this:

```
devServer: {
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/assets/'
},
```